# Does Android 4.0.3 SIP API support NAT?

Tags: android, sip, nat

I am working with Android 4.0.3 SIP Api and was able to make sip call between 2 users on same network. But it is not working if one of the user is behind NAT/Firewall.

1. Does Android SIP api support the NAT? if no, is there any workaround for it.
2. If I find my public IP using some other STUN client, Can I provide this to Android SIP api in SipManager or SipProfile class orin any other class? It seems there is no direct way to do it but any workaroound for it?
3. If NAT is not supported currently, Is there any expectation to have this support in coming Android releases?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the sip library provided by Android. Use a third party one or write your own. The one comes with Android is very limited and not supported on every device.